# Boost asio stops processing after some amount of time

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I have a server application, which uses boost.asio framework. Application logic is simple - it listens on several ports for incoming connections, accepts it, does some processing and closes connection. Of course, more than several clients allowed to connect to server at same time. I use asynchronous approach to accept connection read and write data. The problem is, that at some point of time io_service just stops to process handlers.

Let me describe symptoms in more details. After problem appears, application continues to listen to specified ports, and netstat command can verify that. Client can establish connection to server, but not a single handler(Server::Session) is called.

Here is code, that accepts connections:

```
void Server::StartAccept()
{
     socket_ptr sock(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ioService_));
     acceptor_.async_accept(*sock, boost::bind(&Server::Session, shared_from_this(), sock, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void Server::Session(socket_ptr sock, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
     StartAccept();
     if(error)
     {
          boost::system::error_code ec;
          sock->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
          sock->close(ec);
          return;
     }

     //Processing...
}
```

Here is the code, which starts server:

```
void run_service()
{
     for (;;)
     {
          try
          {
               io_service.run();
               break;
          }
          catch (...)
          {
          }
     }
}

boost::thread_group threads;

for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    threads.create_thread(run_service);

threads.join_all();
```

I found out out, that, if I replace line

```
io_service.run();
```

with

```
while (!io_service.stopped())
    io_service.run_once();
```

than this loop will stuck right when error appears, and run_once function will never return.

My assumptions on why that could happend:

- One of handler, which was called never returns.
- This is some sort of deadlock in boost internals(because I don't do any locking).

The questions are:

- What other reasons could be for such strange behaviour?
- What is best way to fix that?
- How can I figure out, which handler is called by run_once function before it stucks?

Comment: Add some logging features to your code, if the problem can't be reproduced during debugging.

Comment: Consider enabling [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) by defining `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in handler, which waited for another network activity to finish. This activity didn't have timeout and in some cases lasted forever. Thanks for comments. Defining `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` is really good step to detect problem.